# Compilando proyecto en Maven con errores

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Estoy aprendiendo gRPC por necesidades de trabajo y ya por enésima vez cuando realizo proyectos Maven, me encuentro que al ejecutar los proyecto, la primera ejecución funciona correctamente. Luego de hacer unos pocos cambios, o agregar una nueva dependencia al `POM.xml`, y reconstruir el proyecto de nuevo, tengo una alta probabilidad de que falle.

Quiero aprender a controlar estos fallos de maven, creo que es realmente importante. Voy a exponer un caso en particular y me gustaría que orientarais en qué estoy **haciendo mal** o el **porqué del fallo**. He estado revisando en internet los fallos y aunque a ciertas personas parece funcionar a veces una solución, a otros como a mi no me solventan el problema. También estuve mirando por encima la documentación al respecto sobre ciclos de vida de los proyecto maven.

Al caso, me he puesto a realizar este video de youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nxoD-2Mx6I

Son varios vídeos en los que te explica la implementación de los servicios gRPC en Java. En este caso este es el segundo del tutorial creado por el autor **yrrhelp**. El primer vídeo es una explicación, y la agregación de dependencias del pom.xml para generar el proyecto. Hasta aquí bien, lance build, se bajaron las dependencias y el proyecto se genero correctamente.

En el segundo vídeo genera un archivo *.proto; realizado correctamente como manda el tutorial, me dispongo a lanzar maven build como realiza el autor y ¿qué me encuentro? Un error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.yrrhelp:grpcDemo >------------------------
[INFO] Building GrpcDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar7036990016503463967\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar7036990016503463967\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar2212358241670184818\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar2212358241670184818\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3203110273318881987\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3203110273318881987\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3381256017867388334\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3381256017867388334\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.726 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T11:59:15+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project grpcDemo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Solicité ayuda a un amigo que maneja mas que yo de maven, y me aconsejó que lo lanzara desde **cmd** con las variables del sistema, y así lo hice:

```
C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo>mvn clean generate-sources compile install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< com.yrrhelp:grpcDemo >------------------------
[INFO] Building GrpcDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3891767747357790306\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3891767747357790306\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3380880278247623014\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3380880278247623014\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO]
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar8871607500424585441\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar8871607500424585441\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar5479106723019041742\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar5479106723019041742\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3511769371636637656\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3511769371636637656\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar5241047446349736039\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\0016591\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar5241047446349736039\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target\grpcDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target\grpcDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\0016591\.m2\repository\com\yrrhelp\grpcDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\grpcDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\pom.xml to C:\Users\0016591\.m2\repository\com\yrrhelp\grpcDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\grpcDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.614 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T10:45:13+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Se lanzó correctamente. Pero claro, en este punto, no es lo mismo lanzar maven build desde eclipse, que lanzarlo desde cmd con los goals "clean generate-sources compile install", o eso pienso yo, aunque lo desconozco; ahora tambien es cierto que en el pom.xml el autor tiene colocado estos goals por defecto en el build:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.yrrhelp</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpcDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GrpcDemo</name>

  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean generate-sources compile install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <!-- compile proto file into java files. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>

                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/resources</include>
                            </inputDirectories>

                            <outputTargets>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>java</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>grpc-java</type>
                                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0</pluginArtifact>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                            </outputTargets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Realizado estas pruebas, decido lanzar desde la consola un **maven build** el cual genera un error. El resultado es el siguiente:

```
C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo>mvn build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< com.yrrhelp:grpcDemo >------------------------
[INFO] Building GrpcDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.168 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T12:41:53+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

En este punto quisiera preguntar:

1.- ¿Porqué falla al lanzar maven build?

2.- ¿Porqué al realizar desde la consola de comandos "**clean generate-sources compile install**" se construye correctamente?

**Información adicional:**

*Versión java*

```
C:\Users\0016591>java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

*Version Maven*

```
C:\Users\0016591>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: A mí también me daba error después de generar el 1º .war, mi solución : Reiniciar todo el ordenador :) (No es broma)

Comment: Gracias @EduBw pero no me sirve. Ya lo reinicié.

Answer (score 1):

La parte de tu log que indica el error es

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ grpcDemo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\0016591\eclipse-workspace\grpcDemo\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
```

y sucede al ejecutar el plugin llamado `maven-compiler-plugin`, pero el problema no es un error del plugin, sino de tu classpath en eclipse.

A mí me llegó a pasar mucho en esa mugre de IDE que aunque lo configuraba bien, a veces al abrirlo se le cambiaba la configuración, posiblemente porque no la cargaba de un arhivo de configuración... o yo que sé.

Para configurarlo vas a

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
```

[image: jre en vez e jre en eclipse]

Por si siguiera existiendo el bug que a mi me salía te conviene ver el jre que sale seleccionado y en vez de agregar un jdk y dejarlo seleccionado, edita el jre y le pones la ruta de un JDK, así ya no se te moverá la configuración, si te fijas bien en la imágen... es exactamente lo que hicieron porque sigue saliendo con el nombre de jre, pero la ruta es de jdk.

Por tu salida de consola, verás que tu JDK está instalado en `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231`.

Ahora que si le desconfías muchísimo al eclipse y/o te da flojera configurarlo, puedes configurar ese plugin en tu pom para decirle la ruta de tu JDK,

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```